# How do I make a function to change every appearance of a letter to a different letter?

Tags: python

I have a name, let's say "John"

I want to create a function that changes the "o" to an "a"

This is what I came up with

```
def replace(seq,target,rplcmt):
    for letter in seq:
        if letter == target:
            lid = seq.find(letter)
            new_seq = seq[0:lid] + rplcmt + seq[lid+1::]
            return new_seq

name = "John"

newname = replace(name,"o","a")
print(newname)


    "Jahn"
```

This works fine and returns "Jahn", But what if I want to change a name like "Johonas" (for example)

```
def replace(seq,target,rplcmt):
    for letter in seq:
        if letter == target:
            lid = seq.find(letter)
            new_seq = seq[0:lid] + rplcmt + seq[lid+1::]
            return new_seq
    
name = "Johonas"
newname = replace(name,"o","a")
print(newname)


    "Jahonas"
```

It returns Jahonas, so I tried to make an if statement, like so

```
def replace(seq,target,rplcmt):
    for letter in seq:
        if letter == target:
            lid = seq.find(letter)
            new_seq = seq[0:lid] + rplcmt + seq[lid+1::]
            if target not in new_seq:
                return new_seq


name = "Johonas"

newname = replace(name,"o","a")
print(newname)


    None
```

However this return None, and I quite honestly don't know how to fix this, any help is appreciable.

Comment: Seems like your function is a one-liner: `return ''.join(rplcmt if x == target else x for x in seq)`

Comment: But why are you avoiding the `replace` method of the object?  Is this purely for educational purposes?

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your current solution is that, when you return, the function exits before checking if there are more `target`s inside `seq`.

You should create a new variable, named `current_seq`, initialize it to `seq` and, instead of returning, change the value of this variable. You should also use a while-loop, so you iterate only when necessary:

```
def replace(seq,target,rplcmt):
    current_seq = seq
    while target in current_seq:
        lid = current_seq.find(target)
        current_seq = current_seq[0:lid] + rplcmt + current_seq[lid+1::]
    return current_seq

assert(replace("John", "o", "a") == "Jahn")
assert(replace("Johonas", "o", "a") == "Jahanas")
```

With the solution above, you search the `current_seq` for `target` twice: the first in `target in current_seq` and the second in `current_seq.find(target)`. To improve performance, you can use a infinite loop and break when a certain condition is met, searching `current_seq` only once:

```
def replace(seq,target,rplcmt):
    current_seq = seq
    while True:
        lid = current_seq.find(target)
        if lid == -1:
            break
        current_seq = current_seq[0:lid] + rplcmt + current_seq[lid+1::]

    return current_seq
```

Alternatively, you can just use the `str.replace` method:

```
assert(str.replace("John", "o", "a") == "Jahn")
assert(str.replace("Johonas", "o", "a") == "Jahanas")
```